# Prove Geometry automatically

Tags: geometry, proof

If given a geometric problem, can Mathematica solve it automatically? Is there any software that can solve geometry problems automatically?

Comment: Every geometric problem? I doubt it. Some geometric problems? Yes. I doubt anyone can really say more without clarification of the question or an example system to solve.

Comment: I mean how do you want to specify the problem? If you specify it correctly you might be able to make `Solve` work or maybe `FindInstance` and there's also a lot of stuff building on `GeometricScene`, but if you want a _proof_ in the kind of language we're used to there's some stuff with `FindEquationalProof` or whatever that function is called, but a lot of statements won't be amenable to that.

Answer (score 4):

The geometry functionality is described here:

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SyntheticGeometry.html
- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SyntheticGeometry.html